# How to specify the path of file to openFileInputStream method in android?

Tags: android

I want to read a file (mp3 file) using FileInputStream.However i am not able to specify the  path of my file as a parameter to method openFileInput.I have a raw folder placed in res folder within which is my mp3 file.Can someone tell me how to specify the path for that method.I am a newbie to android.

```
 FileInputStream fis;
 fis = openFileInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
InputStream raw = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```

To get an InputStream for that file. You can then construct a BufferedReader or Reader or whatever you want to you and read the data.